# Gulp sass output paths for css.map files Google Chrome can't resolve path

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, gulp

Not sure if this a config problem with Google Chrome, or my Gulp file.

Example:
Expecting to see the correct path to `_selects.scss` within Chrome so I can edit the sass file within Chrome. This sass module is processed inside of `product.scss.` I will use this file in the example.

Chrome tries to load `http://dev.local/Users/simon/ab/public/v4/sass/modules/_selects.scss` which 404s.

Server setup is a Vagrant box that resolves its root to `dev.local`.

Gulp project root: `/Users/simon/ab/public/v4`

Tree view ( many files omitted )

```
/sass
   ├modules
   |      ├ _select.scss 
   ├partials
   ├product.scss ( this file imports _select.scss )
/css
   ├ product.css
   ├ product.css.map
/node_modules
```

product.css.map

```
{
"version": 3,
"mappings": "AAIE;;;;;;;;;;;;wBAYyB;EAiDzB,MAAM,EAAE,CAAC;EACT,OAAO,EAAE,CAAC;EACV,MAAM,EAAE,CAAC;EAIT,IAAI,EAAE,OAAO;EACb,SAAS,EAAE,IAAI;EACf,cAAc,EAAE,QAAQ;;;AApDxB,IAAK;EA6DL,WAAW,EAAE,CAAC;;;AA3Dd,MAAO;EA+DP,UAAU,EAAE,IAAI;;;AA7DhB,KAAM;EAiEN,eAAe,EAAE,QAAQ;EACzB,cAAc,EAAE,CAAC;;;AAhEjB,eAAgB;EAoEhB,UAAU,EAAE,IAAI;EAChB,WAAW,EAAE,MAAM;EACnB,cAAc,EAAE,MAAM;;;AApEtB,aAAc;EAwEd,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;;AACZ,sDAAkB;EAChB,OAAO,EAAE,EAAE;EACX,OAAO,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAzEf,KAAM;EA6EN,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAOZ,sGAAiC;EAC/B,OAAO,EAAE,KAAK;;;;;;;ACnHhB,IAAK;ECQC,kBAAoB,EDPJ,UAAU;ECY1B,eAAiB,EDZD,UAAU;EC2B1B,UAAY,ED3BI,UAAU;;;AAI9B,oBAAqB;ECGjB,kBAAoB,EDFF,OAAO;ECOzB,eAAiB,EDPC,OAAO;ECsBzB,UAAY,EDtBM,OAAO;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;AEyHjC,MAAO;EAZP,KAAK,EAAC,IAAI;ECvFN,KAAK,EAAE,CAAC;;ADwFZ,YAAQ;EACJ,OAAO,EAAE,OAAO;EAChB,OAAO,EAAE,KAAK;EACd,MAAM,EAAE,CAAC;EACT,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,QAAQ,EAAE,MAAM;EAChB,UAAU,EAAE,MAAM;;;AE3HtB,QAAS;EACP,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,OAAO,EAAE,CAAC;EACV,MAAM,EAAE,SAAS;;;AAGnB,YAAa;EACX,YAAY,EAAE,GAAG;EACjB,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;EACZ,MAAM,EAAE,iBAAmB;EAC3B,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,SAAS,EAAE,IAAI;EACf,WAAW,EAAE,MAAM;EACnB,eAAe,EAAE,IAAI;EACrB,MAAM,EAAE,cAAc;EACtB,gBAAgB,EAAE,KAAK;EACvB,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;EACZ,UAAU,EAAE,MAAM;EAClB,gBAAgB,EAAE,4DAA4D;EAC9E,iBAAiB,EAAE,SAAS;EAC5B,mBAAmB,EAAE,SAAS;EAC9B,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;EACZ,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;EACZ,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,GAAG,EAAE,GAAG;EACR,IAAI,EAAE,GAAG;EACT,OAAO,EAAE,KAAK;EACd,QAAQ,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAGhB,QAAS;EACP,QAAQ,EAAE,MAAM;EAChB,gBAAgB,EAAE,IAAI;EACtB,YAAY,EAAE,GAAG;EACjB,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;EACZ,MAAM,EAAE,iBAAmB;EAC3B,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;EACZ,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,MAAM,EAAE,cAAc;EACtB,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;EACZ,MAAM,EAAE,SAAS;;;AAGnB,YAAa;EACX,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,IAAI,EAAE,GAAG;EACT,GAAG,EAAE,GAAG;EACR,UAAU,EAAE,IAAI;;EAEhB,OAAO,EAAE,IAAI;EACb,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;EACZ,OAAO,EAAE,IAAI;EACb,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;;;AAGd,WAAY;EACV,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,IAAI,EAAE,IAAI;EACV,GAAG,EAAE,IAAI;EACT,UAAU,EAAE,IAAI;EAChB,OAAO,EAAE,IAAI;EACb,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;EACZ,OAAO,EAAE,KAAK;EACd,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;;;AAGd,YAAa;EACX,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,MAAM,EAAE,cAAc;EACtB,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;;;AAGd,iBAAkB;EAChB,OAAO,EAAE,KAAK;EACd,UAAU,EAAE,IAAI;EAChB,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;EACZ,WAAW,EAAE,IAAI;EACjB,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,QAAQ,EAAE,MAAM;EAChB,UAAU,EAAE,MAAM;EAClB,SAAS,EAAE,IAAI;EACf,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,GAAG,EAAE,GAAG;EACR,IAAI,EAAE,GAAG;EACT,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;EACZ,YAAY,EAAE,GAAG;EACjB,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;EACZ,MAAM,EAAE,iBAAmB;;;AAG7B,iBAAkB;EAChB,OAAO,EAAE,KAAK;EACd,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,QAAQ,EAAE,MAAM;EAChB,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;;;AAGd,qBAAsB;EACpB,MAAM,EAAE,GAAG;EACX,OAAO,EAAE,KAAK;EACd,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;;;AAGd,WAAY;EACV,OAAO,EAAE,EAAE;EACX,MAAM,EAAE,gBAAkB;EAC1B,YAAY,EAAE,IAAI;EAClB,OAAO,EAAE,IAAI;EACb,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,OAAO,EAAE,KAAK;;;;;;;;;;;;;AC1GhB,aAAc;EACZ,QAAQ,EAAE,MAAM;EAChB,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;;;AAGpB,QAAS;EACP,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;;;AAGpB,eAAgB;EACd,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,GAAG,EAAE,CAAC;EACN,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;EACZ,UAAU,EAAE,OAAO;EACnB,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAGb,iBAAkB;EAChB,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,MAAM,EAAE,CAAC;EACT,IAAI,EAAE,CAAC;EACP,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;EACZ,UAAU,EAAE,GAAG;;;AAGjB;mBACoB;EAClB,MAAM,EAAE,CAAC;EACT,OAAO,EAAE,CAAC;;;AAGZ,OAAQ;EACN,OAAO,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAGf,yBAA0B;EACxB,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAGb,SAAU;EACR,UAAU,EAAE,IAAI;EAChB,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;;;AAGpB,QAAS;EACP,UAAU,EAAE,IAAI;EAChB,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,GAAG,EAAE,CAAC;EACN,IAAI,EAAE,CAAC;EACP,MAAM,EAAE,OAAO;;;AAGjB;0BAC2B;EACzB,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAGd,SAAU;EACR,UAAU,EAAE,OAAO;EACnB,WAAW,EAAE,QAAQ;EACrB,OAAO,EAAE,KAAK;EACd,MAAM,EAAE,OAAO;;;AAGjB,qBAAsB;EACpB,MAAM,EAAE,OAAO;;;AAGjB,yBAA0B;EACxB,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAGd,2BAA4B;EAC1B,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAGd,+BAAgC;EAC9B,OAAO,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAGf,UAAW;EACT,UAAU,EAAE,OAAO;EACnB,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;;;;AAId,iBAAkB;EAChB,MAAM,EAAE,UAAU;;;;AAKpB;;SAEU;EACR,UAAU,EAAE,OAAO;;;AAGrB,QAAS;EACP,UAAU,EAAE,OAAO;;;AAGrB;;cAEe;EACb,UAAU,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAGlB,yBAA0B;EACxB,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAGd,2BAA4B;EAC1B,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAGb,WAAY;EACV,UAAU,EAAE,kFAAkF;;;AAGhG,aAAc;EACZ,UAAU,EAAE,qFAAqF;;;AAGnG,aAAc;EACZ,mBAAmB,EAAE,kBAAkB;;;AAGzC,cAAe;EACb,mBAAmB,EAAE,kBAAkB;;;AC9IzC,OAAQ;EJCN,WAAW,EAAE,8CAA8C;EAC3D,WAAW,EKgFE,GAAG;EL1Dd,SAAS,EKoDM,IAAI;EL7CrB,cAAc,EAAE,SAAS;EACzB,cAAc,EAAE,KAAK;EACrB,KAAK,EKUW,OAAqB;ECiTrC,kBAAwC,EF1VjB,GAAG;EE0V1B,qBAAwC,EC9Sb,GAAuB;ED8SlD,aAAwC,EF1VjB,GAAG;ELOpB,kBAAoB,EKNN,UAAU;ELWxB,eAAiB,EKXH,UAAU;EL0BxB,UAAY,EK1BE,UAAU;EAC9B,OAAO,EAAE,YAAY;EACrB,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,OAAO,EAAE,OAAO;EAChB,KAAK,EC2De,OAAmB;ED1DvC,MAAM,EAAE,OAAO;EACf,kBAAkB,EAAE,IAAI;EACxB,MAAM,EAAE,iBAAkC;EAC1C,UAAU,EAAC,4n9DAEQ;EACnB,WAAW,EAAE,IAAI;EIEb,MAAM,EAAE,mDAAoF;EAGhG,OAAO,EJJU,GAAG;;AAEpB,aAAO;EIHH,MAAM,EAAE,sDAAiE;EAK7E,OAAO,EJDY,CAAC;;AAEpB,WAAM;EJnBN,WAAW,EAAE,8CAA8C;EAC3D,WAAW,EKgFE,GAAG;ELtDd,SAAS,EAAE,IAAc;EAG3B,cAAc,EAAE,SAAS;EACzB,cAAc,EAAE,KAAK;EACrB,KAAK,EKUW,OAAqB;;;ADhBnC,oBAAQ;EAAE,SAAS,EAAE,IAA4B;;;AAIjD,mBAAQ;EAAE,SAAS,EAAE,IAA4B;;;AAIrD,SAAU;EACR,OAAO,EAAE,CAAC;EACV,MAAM,EAAE,CAAC;EJpCT,WAAW,EAAE,8CAA8C;EAC3D,WAAW,EKgFE,GAAG;EL1Dd,SAAS,EKoDM,IAAI;EL7CrB,cAAc,EAAE,SAAS;EACzB,cAAc,EAAE,KAAK;EACrB,KAAK,EKUW,OAAqB;;;ADFvC;;UAEW;EACT,MAAM,EAAE,CAAC;EACT,OAAO,EAAE,CAAC;;;AAGZ,UAAW;EACT,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,KAAK,EAAE,OAAO;;;AAGhB,UAAW;EACP,UAAU,EAAC,4n9DAEF;;;AAGb;;cAEe;EACb,KAAK,ECIe,OAAmB;EDHvC,eAAe,EAAE,IAAI;EACrB,OAAO,EAAE,IAAI;EACb,MAAM,EAAE,YAAY;EACpB,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;EACZ,OAAO,EAAE,KAAK;;;AAGhB,eAAgB;EACd,KAAK,ECLe,OAAmB;;;ADQzC,aAAc;EACZ,UAAU,EAAE,2BAA2B;EACvC,OAAO,EAAE,IAAI;EACb,IAAI,EAAE,IAAI;EACV,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,KAAK,EAAE,OAAO;EACd,MAAM,EAAE,iBAAkC;EAC1C,GAAG,EAAE,CAAC;EACN,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;EACZ,gBAAgB,EAAE,CAAC;;;AAGrB,0CAA2C;EACzC,SAAS,EAAE,IAAI;EACf,KAAK,EAAE,KAAK;EACZ,UAAU,EAAE,MAAM;EAClB,gBAAgB,EAAE,GAAG;EACrB,GAAG,EAAE,IAAI;EACT,WAAW,EAAE,IAAI;EACjB,WAAW,EAAE,KAAK;;;AAGpB,YAAa;ELvFL,kBAAoB,EKwFN,UAAU;ELnFxB,eAAiB,EKmFH,UAAU;ELpExB,UAAY,EKoEE,UAAU;;;AAGhC,kBAAmB;EACjB,OAAO,EAAE,GAAG;EACZ,OAAO,EAAE,KAAK;;;AAGhB,oCAAqC;EACnC,gBAAgB,ECzEY,OAAO;ED0EnC,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAGb,8CAA+C;EAC7C,UAAU,EAAE,IAAI;EAChB,KAAK,EC9Ce,OAAmB;;;AIlEzC,eAAgB;EACd,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,OAAO,EAAE,CAAC;EACV,OAAO,EAAE,iBAAkC;EAC3C,KAAK,EAAE,KAAK;EACZ,QAAQ,EAAE,MAAM;EAChB,gBAAgB,EJ4DI,OAAmB;;AI3DvC,kBAAG;EACD,MAAM,EAAE,KAAK;EACb,UAAU,EAAE,iBAAiB;EAC7B,MAAM,EAAE,CAAC;EACT,QAAQ,EAAE,MAAM;EAChB,OAAO,EAAE,CAAC;EACV,KAAK,EAAE,KAAK;;AAEd,6BAAc;EACZ,KAAK,EAAE,KAAK;EACZ,MAAM,EAAE,KAAK;EACb,QAAQ,EAAE,MAAM;;AAElB,0BAAW;EACT,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,OAAO,EAAE,KAAK;EACd,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;EACZ,SAAS,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAInB,mBAAoB;EAClB,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EVpBL,kBAAoB,EUqBN,UAAU;EVhBxB,eAAiB,EUgBH,UAAU;EVDxB,UAAY,EUCE,UAAU;EAC9B,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,UAAU,EJkCU,OAAmB;EIjCvC,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;EACZ,QAAQ,EAAE,QAAQ;EAClB,OAAO,EAAE,CAAC;;AAER,6CAAU;ETrCZ,WAAW,EAAE,8CAA8C;EAC3D,WAAW,EKkFD,GAAG;EL5DX,SAAS,EKoDM,IAAI;EL7CrB,cAAc,EAAE,SAAS;EACzB,cAAc,EAAE,KAAK;EACrB,KAAK,EKUW,OAAqB;EIHjC,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;EACZ,MAAM,EAAE,OAAO;EACf,OAAO,EAAE,CAAC;;AACV,gDAAG;EACD,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,MAAM,EAAE,IAAI;EACZ,WAAW,EAAE,IAAI;EACjB,UAAU,EAAE,iBAAiB;EAC7B,MAAM,EAAE,UAAU;EAClB,OAAO,EAAE,CAAC;EACV,KAAK,EAAC,IAAI;;AAEZ,+CAAE;EACA,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI;EACX,WAAW,EAAE,GAAG;EAChB,cAAc,EAAE,GAAG;EACnB,WAAW,EAAE,MAAM;EACnB,WAAW,EAAE,GAAG;EAChB,SAAS,EAAE,IAAI;;AAIrB,6CAA0B;ED/CtB,MAAM,EAAE,mDAAoF;EAGhG,OAAO,EC6CY,GAAG;;AAGtB,qDAAmC;EDrD/B,MAAM,EAAE,sDAAiE;EAK7E,OAAO,ECiDY,CAAC;;;AC7DrB,yBAAQ;EACN,UAAU,EAAE,IAAI;EAChB,OAAO,EAAE,KAAK;EACd,WAAW,EAAE,IAAI;EACjB,KAAK,EAAE,KAAK;EACZ,KAAK,EAAE,KAAK;;AAEd,oBAAG;EACF,gBAAgB,EAAE,IAAI;;;AAIxB,2BAA4B;EAC3B,GAAG,EAAC,eAAe",
"sources": [
    "../../../../../../../Users/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/reset/_utilities.scss",
    "../../../../../../../Users/simon/ab/public/v4/sass/neat/grid/_box-sizing.scss",
    "../../../../../../../Users/simon/ab/public/v4/sass/bourbon/addons/_prefixer.scss",
    "../../../../../../../Users/simon/ab/public/v4/sass/partials/_mixins.scss",
    "../../../../../../../Users/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/utilities/general/_hacks.scss",
    "../../../../../../../Users/simon/ab/public/v4/sass/vendor/jquery.jqzoom.scss",
    "../../../../../../../Users/simon/ab/public/v4/sass/vendor/jquery.jscrollpane.scss",
    "../../../../../../../Users/simon/ab/public/v4/sass/modules/_selects.scss",
    "../../../../../../../Users/simon/ab/public/v4/sass/partials/_variables.scss",
    "../../../../../../../Users/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/_support.scss",
    "../../../../../../../Users/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/css3/_border-radius.scss",
    "../../../../../../../Users/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/css3/_opacity.scss",
    "../../../../../../../Users/simon/ab/public/v4/sass/modules/_product-slider.scss",
    "../product.scss"
],
"names": [],
"file": "product.css"
}
```

Product.css file `/*# sourceMappingURL=product.css.map */`

Package JSON

```
{
"name": "XXX-website",
"version": "0.1.0",
"description": "XXX",
"repository": "private",
"author": "XXX",
"devDependencies": {
  "browser-sync": "^1.6.3",
  "gulp": "^3.8.10",
  "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.0.0",
  "gulp-cache": "^0.2.4",
  "gulp-chmod": "^1.2.0",
  "gulp-concat": "^2.4.2",
  "gulp-imagemin": "^2.0.0",
  "gulp-jshint": "^1.9.0",
  "gulp-livereload": "^2.1.1",
  "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.11",
  "gulp-notify": "^2.0.1",
  "gulp-plumber": "^0.6.6",
  "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
  "gulp-ruby-sass": "^0.7.1",
  "gulp-strip-code": "^0.1.2",
  "gulp-uglify": "^1.0.1",
  "gulp-util": "^3.0.1",
  "underscore": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Gulp File ( omitted js task and image tasks )

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
return gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        compass: true,
        style: 'expanded',
        sourcemap: true,
        sourcemapPath : '../sass',
    }))
    .pipe(chmod(644))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/min'))
    .pipe(notify({
        message: 'Styles task complete'
    }))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

In Chrome I have enabled CSS source maps with reload Auto-reload generated CSS checked.

The working directory is `Users/simon/ab/public/v4/`

Entire Gulp File:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    _ = require("underscore"),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    stripCode = require('gulp-strip-code'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    chmod = require('gulp-chmod');



var stripCodeOptions = {
    start_comment: "test-code",
    end_comment: "end-test-code"
};

function buildJs(files, output) {
    return gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
        .pipe(stripCode(stripCodeOptions))
        .pipe(concat(output))
        .pipe(chmod(644))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/dist'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/min'))
        .pipe(notify({
            message: output + ' task complete'
        }))
        .pipe(livereload());
};

var scripts = [{
    output: 'global.js',
    input: [
        'js/lib/modernizr.2.8.3.js',
        'js/lib/jquery-1.11.1.js',
        'js/lib/jquery.lazyload.1.9.3.js',
        'js/lib/tinypubsub.0.7.js',
        'js/lib/jquery.fancybox.1.3.4.js',
        'js/lib/jquery.alerts.js',
        'js/module/ab.utils.js',
        'js/module/ab.module.modal.js',
        'js/module/plugins.js',
        'js/module/*', // gulp is smart enough not to load file again.
        'js/main-deprecated.js'
    ]
}, {
    output: 'home.js',
    input: [
        'js/lib/swipe.2.0.js',
        'js/home.js'
    ]
}, {
    output: 'faq.js',
    input: [
        'js/lib/jquery.mousewheel.js',
        'js/lib/jquery.jscrollpane.2.0.19.js',
        'js/lib/jquery.highlight.js',
        'js/faq.js'
    ]
}, {
    output: 'range.js',
    input: [
        'js/lib/handlebars-v2.0.0.js',
        'js/lib/jquery.lockfixed.js',
        'js/search.js',
        'js/range.js'
    ]
}, {
    output: 'product.js',
    input: [
        'js/lib/jquery.easyfade.js',
        'js/lib/froogaloop.2.0.js',
        'js/lib/jquery.mousewheel.js',
        'js/lib/jquery.jqzoom.2.3.js',
        'js/lib/jquery.jscrollpane.2.0.19.js',
        'js/lib/swipe.2.0.js',
        'js/lib/jquery.qtip.2.2.1.js',
        'js/product.js'
    ]
}, {
    output: 'video.js',
    input: [
        'js/lib/froogaloop.2.0.js',
        'js/lib/history.js',
        'js/lib/mustache.js',
        'js/ausbumtv.js'
    ]
}, {
    output: 'checkout.js',
    input: [
        'js/lib/jquery.activeform.1.1.1.js',
        'js/lib/jquery.sticky.kit.1.0.4.js',
        'js/lib/jquery.qtip.2.2.1.js',
        'js/ab.module.tooltips.js',
        'js/lib/autocomplete.js',
        'js/checkout.js'
    ]
}, {
    output: 'cart.js',
    input: [
        'js/cart.js'
    ]
}, {
    output: 'members.js',
    input: [
        'js/members.js'
    ]
}, {
    output: 'giftvoucher.js',
    input: [
        'js/giftvoucher.js'
    ]
}];

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            compass: true,
            style: 'expanded',
            sourcemap: true,
            sourcemapPath : '.',
        }))
        .pipe(chmod(644))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/min'))
        .pipe(notify({
            message: 'Styles task complete'
        }))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task("buildjs", function() {
    _.each(scripts, function(script, i) {
        gulp.watch(script.input, function() {
            buildJs(script.input, script.output);
        });
    });
});

gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src('img/**/*')
        .pipe(cache(imagemin({
            optimizationLevel: 3,
            progressive: true,
            interlaced: true
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('img/'))
        .pipe(notify({
            message: 'Images task complete'
        }));
});

//default task to run when running just "gulp"
gulp.task('default', [], function() {
    gulp.start('styles', 'buildjs');
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {

    livereload.listen();

    // Watch .scss files
    gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(['js/*.js', 'js/module/*'], {
        maxListeners: 999
    }, ['buildjs']);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using gulp-sass or gulp-ruby-sass ?

If you are using gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps is required for source map support.
Check out [docs](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass)

If your are using gulp-ruby-sass version < 1.0.0, you have to set sourcemap option along with sourcemapPath

Comment: I am using `gulp-ruby-sass 0.7.1`. I added the sourcemap option. I see it's doubling up the path. `http://dev.local/public/v4/css/sass/Users/simon/ab/public/v4/sass/modules/_free-flow-products.scss`

Comment: Try { sourcemapPath: '.' }

Comment: This makes no difference. Will post entire gulp file now.

Comment: For whatever reason, it is working now. { sourcemapPath : ''../sass' }